# Authentication from a web app where auth is done already

Tags: rest, security, authentication

I have a web application where the users can log in after authentication (user + password). I have another application where some REST service resides that I want to call from the web application.

As the user is already authenticated in the web app so I thought the following scenario can work:

1. Creating a token (with expiration date in it) in the web app when the user logs in
2. When calling the REST service this token can be put to the HTTP header
3. The REST can see that there is this special token in the header so it knows that it has to call back to the web application to check if the token is valid
4. The web application can confirm / reject the token
5. If the token is valid then the REST service can perform the HTTP verb (GET, PUT, etc.)
6. If not valid then retrieve with an HTTP error code

I know there are some already implemented authentication protocol (like OAuth) that does the same but the scenario looks simple enough to implement it without adding any unnecessary infrastucture , etc.

Do you think it can work? If it can what should I pay attention to?
If it cannot why not? What can you recommend instead?

Sorry for the many question! :) Thanks for the help!

Regards,
V.

Comment: I would rather rely on industry tried and trusted authentication protocols (exactly `OAuth`) rather than trying to reinvent the wheel and maybe missing an edge case or two

Comment: Yes, I had the same thought but when I was thinking a little bit I realize that it might be easy to implement the scenario above. I just don't know if there is any pitfall that I can fall into.

Answer (score 0):

If the rest service app is in the same sub domain as your web app and if the web application uses a session after authentication, why not just propagate that to the rest services application? All you have to is to configure the same session cookie in your rest app. That way authentication is automatic and has no overhead of creating and maintaining tokens. More importantly it would save you the overhead and improve performance as you dont have to have a callback for validating the token every time.

Comment: Thanks ramp for the reply! I cannot guarantee that I am afraid. The web application can run in a different sub-domain and I wouldn't want to add any restriction to my app.